# how to cancel HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem

Tags: asp.net, async-await, cancellation-token

Is there a way to cancel background task made with `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`?

There is `CancellationToken` which notifies if tasks was cancelled but how can i do it? 
Refering to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx

> A successful cancellation involves the requesting code calling the CancellationTokenSource.Cancel method

OK. Where can i get access to `CancellationTokenSource`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After few trials i came up with the soulution:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
{
    var linkedTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct);
    var cancellationToken = linkedTokenSource.Token;
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
         // do stuff on background
    }, cancellationToken);
});
```

**Update:**

Indeed, task is not needed. Thanks svick for bringing that up.
Here is a bit more detailed code sample without task.

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
{
    var linkedTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct);
    // following is a dummy method, but you get the idea.
    // StoreCancellationTokenSourceSoItCanBeUsedSomewhereElse(linkedTokenSource);

    var cancellationToken = linkedTokenSource.Token;

    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            // do bg stuff
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        // either token is in cancelled state
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to run the code on a separate `Task` just to be able to cancel it.

Comment: Behind the scene, Task is created anyway, if you use the other overload. And by creating linked token source, i have to manage only one cancallation token. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx "Creates a CancellationTokenSource that will be in the canceled state when any of the source tokens are in the canceled state."

Comment: [I don't see any `Task` created there](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/HostingEnvironment.cs,32c143ca4ed232c1) (and I looked all the way to the place where the code is actually executed). And if you want to combine two ways to cancel, then `CreateLinkedTokenSource()` is the right solution, I didn't say anything against that.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is:

```
public static void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> workItem)
```

This means that a work item gets access to a `CancellationToken`. But I don't think that's useful in your case. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The provided CancellationToken will be signaled when the application is shutting down.

If you want to cancel the `workItem` based on some other condition, you can use a separate `CancellationToken`, which you create from a `CancellationTokenSource`. For example, to cancel a work item if it doesn't start within 10 seconds:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(_ =>
{
    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // the code of the work item goes here
});
```

This will technically still start the work item, even if the `CancellationToken` is cancelled, but it won't do anything.

Note that cancellation is always cooperative. This means that if you have a long-running work item, and you want to cancel it in the middle of its execution, you will need to keep checking the `CancellationToken` periodically.