# Can IIS / ASP.NET abort the HTTP request when client has closed the connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Imagine that an HTTP request is taking a long time to process in ASP.NET, and an impatient user refreshes the page several times. Now I have several copies of the same request running, making things even slower to respond.

I would like IIS to abort the thread if the client has closed the connection while the request is still being processed. IIS can already abort the thread on timeout, but I want the thread to be *only* aborted if the client has closed the connection.

I know that I could be checking `Response.IsClientConnected` while the request is progressing, but that would be a lot checks sprinkled across hundreds of methods. I just want the thread to be aborted automatically as soon as the client has disconnected.

Comment: If you have long running processes, don't run them in an HTTP request. Kick off a [background process](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Comment: Suppose I do that. I still need the background process to be aborted if the client is gone. How do I do that?

Comment: The web is stateless. You'd just need to wait until you've decided they're gone and then kill the background job. Either way, do not do long running tasks in an HTTP request context.

Comment: `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` returns void. How do I kill such background job?

Comment: Awesome question! My brain keeps saying "if the client/browser _reuses the same connection..."_ how would one actually identify "this" connection...

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225472/how-to-cancel-hostingenvironment-queuebackgroundworkitem).

Comment: Mason, in that question they are suggesting to periodically call `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` to cancel background task. If I was in a position to make periodic checks I would simply check Response.IsClientConnected without any background tasks, but I said in my question I can't afford to add dozens/hundreds of checks in various places.

Comment: EdSF, if the user navigates away to a different page still reusing the connection, somehow the browser does not render the contents of the previous page. So there must be some sort of "reset" in HTTP/1.1 that communicates to the server to stop sending stale data even if the TCP/IP connection is still open.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to put restrictions of request /response to some seconds i.e. 5 to 10 seconds. If request fails give them retry option. Also.,while request is being served put busy progress bar or fade out the screen for best UI experience. That's what I did for one of my project and each and every user was so happy that now they know server is busy and will respond back you soon.

Comment: I specifically said that timeout will not work for me: [...]IIS can already abort the thread on timeout, but I want the thread to be ONLY aborted if the client has closed the connection.[...]

Comment: then ,you have to either switch to persistent HTTP connection, which I think you are not going to like. http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPPersistentConnectionEstablishmentManagementand.htm

Comment: one more concept that can be useful is SignalR.check this https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections